How to reduce a list of movements in space
Given a list of movements, such as movements are one of: { forward, up, down, turnLeft, turnRight }, how can I get the most reduced list?
Let's write them using letters: F, U, D, L, R
The first obvious step is to remove opposite moves. So for example { U,D } should be reduced to { }
But then, there are equivalences which I don't know how to determine.
For example, { F,D,R,R,F } is equivalent to { D }. How can I make sure the list is reduced to its bare minimum, or at least to a reasonable minimum? I guess there should be some lookup table that can be constructed but my research on this lead to nothing, I don't have the right vocabulary to search meaningfully.
It reminds me a bit of how Banach-Tarski paradox is constructed.
If you have any theorems to point to, or even algorithms, please let me know.

A very general version of what you're describing is a string rewriting system, and the Knuth-Bendix algorithm can convert some rewriting systems into confluent ones, providing a "reduction" algorithm. But if you're just dealing with movements in Euclidean space, a simpler approach is to find where the given path ends up and output a canonical short path to that location (as smichr's answer suggests).

The simple concept here is 3-dimensional turtle graphics and there are answers about how to keep track of where the turtle is for different commands like these. You can read the answers to this question. There will be equally compact ways to represent where you are using unit motions; this is the taxicab description of how to get from A to B. How far you travelled does not matter, only where you are at the end relative to the start (and you could describe that final displacement in more than one way).
